# Jira Rest Java Client

Tags: java, jira-rest-api

i want to connect to my jira instance in java via Rest-Api. That's why i implement first the connection to the host.

I read a lot of tutorials and i found JRJC. But nothing has worked.

*updated

```
    package com.jira.main;

    import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.URISyntaxException;

    import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.JiraRestClient;
    import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.JiraRestClientFactory;
    import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.domain.Issue;
    import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.domain.User;
    import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;
    import com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise;



public class App 
{

    private static URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/jira");

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws URISyntaxException
    {

        // Construct the JRJC client
        System.out.println(String.format("Logging in to %s with username '%s' and password '%s'", "http://localhost:8080/", "bwanke", "Jako2014W!"));
        final AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory =  new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        final com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, "bwanke", "Jako2014!");


        // Invoke the JRJC Client
        Promise<com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.User> promise = client.getUserClient().getUser("bwanke");
        com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.User user = promise.claim();


        Promise<com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue> promiseIssue = client.getIssueClient().getIssue("TEST-1");
        com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue issue = promiseIssue.claim();

        // Print the result
        System.out.println(String.format("Your admin user's email address is: %s\r\n", user.getEmailAddress()));

        // Print the result
        System.out.println("some TEST-1 details " + issue.getAssignee() + "   " + issue.getSummary() + "  " + issue.getWorklogs());
        // Done
        System.out.println("Example complete. Now exiting.");
        System.exit(0);




    }
}
```

I tried to import the following libraries: jira-rest-java-client-2.0.0-m2.jar, jira-rest-java-client-3.0.0.jar and jira-rest-java-client-4.0.0.jar

But i have still one problem. He can't find Promise

This part:

```
// Invoke the JRJC Client
Promise<User> promise = client.getUserClient().getUser("ezizconduct");
User user = promise.claim();


Promise<Issue> promiseIssue = client.getIssueClient().getIssue("TEST-1");
Issue issue = promiseIssue.claim();
```

The Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Promise cannot be resolved to a type
    The type com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    The method getUser(String) from the type UserRestClient refers to the missing type Promise
    Promise cannot be resolved to a type
    The method getIssue(String) from the type IssueRestClient refers to the missing type Promise

    at com.jira.main.main(main.java:23)
```

Does anyone has an idea?

.
.
.

---------------- Updated - Try with Maven -------------------

- I created a new maven - project
- Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart 1.1
- GroupId and Artifact ID

Then i have a new project in eclipse. I copied my old code from above to the new project. Then i have copied the dependencies from: https://github.com/eziztm/jira_rest_api_test/blob/master/pom.xml

I don't import any libraries, but he doesn't regonize any classes.

My Poem.xml is now:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>main</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>main</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
            <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- JRJC is distributed under the Apache 2.0 license. -->
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>   






    </dependencies>


        <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-public</id>
            <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The type com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

You need to provide transitive dependency of `com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise` which requires at runtime. Add following dependency into your POM will resolve the reported issue.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.atlassian.util.concurrent</groupId>
 <artifactId>atlassian-util-concurrent</artifactId>
 <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Okay, i have updated the content of my post. Is that the right way?